# Save key-value pair in .GlobalPreferences using Swift

Tags: swift, macos

I'm writing a short Mac app (let's call it "myApp") and I need to read from and write to the .GlobalPreferences plist in ~/Library/Preferences/.

For the reading part, I use the following and it's working fine:

```
let boolValue = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("aKeyInGlobalPreferences")
```

However, I'm having some trouble in changing the value for that same key. I tried the following:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "aKeyInGlobalPreferences")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Sadly, it didn't change the key value in .GlobalPreferences. Instead, it created a new plist com.myName.myApp with the key-value pair in there.

How can I make my app write to .GlobalPreferences instead of creating a new plist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write specifically into the global domain with `setPersistentDomain()`.

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setPersistentDomain(["aKeyInGlobalPreferences":true],
    forName: NSGlobalDomain)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. However, it deletes everything in .GlobalPreferences. To fix it I loaded the plist to a dictionary, changed the pair and then setPersistentDomain with the dictionary as the argument.

Comment: I wonder why it behaves this way, because it's really strange. That "read, modify, write" introduces a race condition (unlikely, but technically possible that some other app has written a value to the global domain between your read and write, which will clobber their addition). Why can't we just `UserDefaults.init(suiteName: UserDefaults.globalDomain)`? :|

Comment: I also found a bug in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults/1408187-setpersistentdomain): "Calling this method is equivalent to initializing a user defaults object with `initWithSuiteName:` passing `domainName`, ..." ... nope. Trying to do that yields `Using NSGlobalDomain as an NSUserDefaults suite name does not make sense and will not work. Break on _NSUserDefaults_Log_Nonsensical_Suites to find this`